# Visual studio 2015 RDLC Text in table cell look fine in preview but overflow when print

Tags: rdlc, reportviewer

Text in table cell overflow when print

I set CanGrow to false

In preview (Censor patient name)
https://i.stack.imgur.com/TszgB.png

When print
https://i.stack.imgur.com/Paw22.jpg